How to stop showing inactive slides in vue swiper?
I'm trying to make this https://stories-slider.uiinitiative.com/ slider for stories, but it doesn't work.
The first problem is that after changing the parent slide, the child slider, the previous parent, everything works smoothly and when I go back, the slides actively change instead of pausing after I go back to the parent slide.
The second problem is that I can’t understand how, when returning back to the previous parent slide in the StoriesWrapper.vue component, reload the active slide in the child StoriesIten.vue
And the third problem, I can’t figure out how, after moving to the last element of the child slider or the first, after clicking again, go to either the previous parent slide or the next parent slide
StoriesWrapper.vue
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import { Pagination, Autoplay, EffectCube } from 'swiper/modules';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/effect-cube';

const mainSwiperRef = ref(null);

const activeMainSlideIndex = ref(1);

const handleMainSwiperSlideChange = (swiper) => {
  activeMainSlideIndex.value = swiper.activeIndex + 1;
};

const handleSwiperEndSlide = (parentIndex, swiper) => {
  if (activeMainSlideIndex.value === parentIndex) {
    const mainSwiper = mainSwiperRef.value?.swiper;

    if (swiper.isEnd && !mainSwiper.isEnd) {
      mainSwiper.slideNext();
    } else if (swiper.isBeginning) {
      mainSwiper.slidePrev();
    }
    console.log(`Swiper ${parentIndex} ended slide change`, swiper);
  }
};

const handleMainSwiperInit = (swiper) => {
  mainSwiperRef.value = { swiper };
};
</script>

<template>
  <swiper
    ref="mainSwiperRef"
    :effect="'cube'"
    :cube-effect="{
      shadow: false,
      slideShadows: false,
      shadowOffset: 0,
      shadowScale: 0,
    }"
    :slides-per-view="1"
    :space-between="0"
    :loop="false"
    :modules="[Pagination, Autoplay, EffectCube]"
    class="!h-full main-swiper"
    @swiper="handleMainSwiperInit"
    @slide-change="handleMainSwiperSlideChange"
  >
    <swiper-slide
      v-for="mainIndex in 2"
      :key="mainIndex"
      v-slot="{ isActive }"
      class="relative !h-[60vh]"
    >
      <StoriesItem
        :parent-index="mainIndex"
        :on-swiper-end="
          (parentIndex, swiper) => handleSwiperEndSlide(parentIndex, swiper)
        "
        :is-active="isActive"
      />
    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>

StoriesItem.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import { Pagination, Autoplay, Navigation } from 'swiper/modules';
import 'swiper/css';

const props = defineProps<{
  parentIndex: number;
  onSwiperEnd: Function;
  isActive: boolean;
}>();

const swiperRef = ref();

const isFirstItem = ref(false);

const handleSwiperSlideChange = (swiper) => {
  if (props.isActive && typeof props.onSwiperEnd === 'function') {
    if (swiper.isEnd) {
      swiper.autoplay.stop();
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Время показа последнего слайда закончилось');
        props.onSwiperEnd(props.parentIndex, swiper);
      }, swiper.params.autoplay.delay);
    }

    if (swiper.isBeginning && swiper.activeIndex === 0 && !isFirstItem.value) {
      isFirstItem.value = true;
      swiper.autoplay.start();
    } else if (
      swiper.isBeginning &&
      swiper.activeIndex === 0 &&
      isFirstItem.value
    ) {
      isFirstItem.value = false;
      props.onSwiperEnd(props.parentIndex, swiper);
    }
  }
};

const handleMainSwiperInit = (swiper) => {
  swiperRef.value = { swiper };
};

watch(
  () => [props.isActive, swiperRef.value],
  (newIsActive) => {
    if (swiperRef.value?.swiper) {
      if (newIsActive) {
        swiperRef.value?.swiper.autoplay.stop();
        swiperRef.value?.swiper.slideTo(swiperRef.value?.swiper.activeIndex, 0);
        swiperRef.value?.swiper.autoplay.start();
      } else {
        swiperRef.value?.swiper.autoplay.stop();
      }
    }
  },
  {
    immediate: true
  }
);
</script>

<template>
  <div class="relative w-full h-full">
    <div
      class="absolute right-0 inset-y-0 w-1/2 cursor-pointer z-[3]"
      :class="`story__next_${props.parentIndex}`"
    ></div>
    <div
      class="absolute left-0 inset-y-0 w-1/2 cursor-pointer z-[3]"
      :class="`story__prev_${props.parentIndex}`"
    ></div>

    <div
      class="absolute top-4 flex w-full gap-6 px-6 z-[4]"
      :class="`story__pagination_${props.parentIndex}`"
    ></div>

    <swiper
      ref="swiperRef"
      :slides-per-view="1"
      :space-between="0"
      :watch-slides-progress="false"
      :modules="[Pagination, Autoplay, Navigation]"
      :autoplay="{
        delay: 3900,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      }"
      :loop="false"
      class="sub-swiper !h-full"
      :navigation="{
        nextEl: `.story__next_${props.parentIndex}`,
        prevEl: `.story__prev_${props.parentIndex}`,
      }"
      :pagination="{
        el: `.story__pagination_${props.parentIndex}`,
        type: 'bullets',
        clickable: true,
        bulletClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet',
        bulletActiveClass: 'swiper-pagination-bullet-active',
      }"
      @slide-change="handleSwiperSlideChange"
      @swiper="handleMainSwiperInit"
    >
      <swiper-slide
        v-for="subIndex in 4"
        :key="subIndex"
        class="bg-red-400 !h-full"
      >
        <h2>
          {{ "parentIndex_" + props.parentIndex + "_____Slide_" + subIndex }}
        </h2>
      </swiper-slide>
    </swiper>
  </div>
</template>

